# Floodfill in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flood-fill

I am trying for a coloring app and to figure out floodfill in objective c anybody did this before..???I am reading all pixel data in a picture and i can change it also..but floodfill can only do what i want exactly.. [image: Sample Image]..Here I Can identify the pixels containing black dot also.but I am really confuse how to identify the pixels in a particular white area.Any help is appreciated..

Comment: vote up for framing your question so beautifully.

Comment: have you found anything on this?, i am trying to do something like this... and i haven't any code on this.

Comment: http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/   Start with this one .

Comment: did you figure out this?

Comment: http://www.techques.com/question/1-5931552/Flood-Filling-in-iPad-too-SLOW

Comment: https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Comment: @ sat have u made this , can u provide help regarding this ASAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself [This link](http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/) really helped me to identify the black and white dot in particular pixels.[flood filling](http://code-heaven.blogspot.com/2009/05/c-program-to-implement-flood-fill.html) is explained here.

Answer (score 1):

Theres lots of source code available for flood fill algos. You can probably find a good one and throw it in a method

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c+flood+fill+algorithm

If its been written in C/C++ you can use it in Objective-C

Comment: how to use this algorithm in the objective c helo me Warren Burton