# Flood filling in iPad too slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, flood-fill

I am using flood Filling for one of my coloring apps on iPad.

The app basically fills color within the black line of the image and I am able to do this with no problem, but it's too slow.

I first used recursive flood fill and its performance is the worst (due to Stack Overflow), then I was able to convert it to iterative using Stack with the following code but this is too slow

```
-(void)floodFillAtPoint:(CGPoint)atPoint
 {
Stack *stack = [[Stack alloc] init];

[stack push:[StackPoint pointWithPoint:atPoint]];
StackPoint *currentPoint = nil;
int counter = 0;
while ((currentPoint = [stack pop])) 
{
    CGPoint aPoint = currentPoint.point;//CGPointMake(pointPixel.x, pointPixel.y);
    [self setColorAtPoint:aPoint];
    CGPoint bPoint = aPoint;
    bPoint.x+=1;
    if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        [stack push:[StackPoint pointWithPoint:bPoint]];
    bPoint = aPoint;
    bPoint.x-=1;
    if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        [stack push:[StackPoint pointWithPoint:bPoint]];
    bPoint = aPoint;
    bPoint.y+=1;
    if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        [stack push:[StackPoint pointWithPoint:bPoint]];
    bPoint = aPoint;
    bPoint.y-=1;
    if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        [stack push:[StackPoint pointWithPoint:bPoint]];        
    counter++;
}
[stack release];

}
```

Would anyone suggest an alternative method which works best on iPad device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floodfill in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802138/floodfill-in-objective-c)

Comment: @ quixoto the answer to that one is "use flood fill".  not really relevant, I think, and definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: @RVN, Can you please share the code here?

Comment: @EmptyStack : i have updated my Question with the code snippet

Comment: I am not able to get result with your code.. Please can you help me out?

Comment: @dimple : What is the problem you face ? some customization will be required to get it work right.

Comment: I customized that but somehow or the other I was not able to pass validations.

Comment: Thanks , i did some modification , and it is working , Thanks

Comment: Still i am not getting this work. Can someone help me on this sending me the code.

Comment: Can you help me on this, ... i'm having trouble with "StackPoint"

Comment: @florjan , i have added the StackPoint Class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an Objective-C object to represent each and every pixel is going to be extremely slow and add little benefit.

Use a different data structure to represent your bitmap, like one of the various CG* bitmap encapsulation mechanisms.  Then twiddle the bits in the bitmap directly.  It'll be tons and tons faster.

Comment: Hi @bbum: i can understand what you are trying to say , but any head start would be helpful , a link or the topic in the developer guide

Comment: Flood filling a bitmap image is Computer Graphics 101 material.  A google search will reveal, literal, 10s of thousands of documents discussing exactly that.  There are also tons of CoreGraphics tutorials and examples available, too.  Start with the Apple provided CoreGraphics documentation.

Comment: Agree with @bbum.  If you rewrite your Objective C stuff in straight ANSI C with a C array of CG bitmap pixels, it will likely be a lot faster.  If you don't know C, you don't know Objective C.

Comment: I Used the linked list (Queue) and some struct's and the speed improved considerably, mostly the memory used was much low. Thanks for the help, will post the resultant code soon.

Comment: Hello guys I have tried the above code. It is working fine however I am finding difficult with large images. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)_.

I finally managed to make an acceptable floodfill for iPhone/iPad with following class. Please excuse if any zombie code :). Suggestions for improvement always welcome.

### How to use

Create the CanvasView Object and set the originalImage (this should be the uncolored/colored image with black lines and the area outside the black lines must be clear color) and you can access the coloredImage for the image after paint.

The .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SoundEngine.h"

struct  COLOR {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
};

typedef struct COLOR COLOR;

@interface CanvasView : UIView {
    UIImage *originalImage;
    UIImage *coloredImage;
    int selectedColor;
    BOOL shouldShowOriginalImage;

    UIImageView *imageView;
    BOOL isImageDataFreed;

    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha1;
    int loopCounter;
    NSMutableArray *pixelDataArray;
    BOOL isFilling;
    BOOL hasColored;
    id delegate;
    CGPoint restartPoint;

    BOOL fillAtPoint;
    CGPoint currentTouchPoint;
    int regionCount;
    NSTimer *floadFillTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *coloredImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *originalImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pixelDataArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldShowOriginalImage;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasColored;
@property (assign) int regionCount;

-(void)toggleImage;
-(void)setColor:(int)colorIndex;
-(void)freeImageData;
-(CGColorRef)getColorForIndex:(int)index;
-(void)initializeCanvas;
-(void)prepareImageData;
-(void)setColorForColoring;
@end
```

And the .m file

```
#import "CanvasView.h"
#import "PaintGame.h"
#import "Color.h"
#import "FarvespilletAppDelegate.h"
#import "Stack.h"
#import "Point.h"


@implementation CanvasView
@synthesize coloredImage,originalImage,pixelDataArray,delegate,shouldShowOriginalImage,hasColored;
@synthesize regionCount;

unsigned char *imageRawData;

-(COLOR)getPixelColorAtIndex:(CGPoint)atPoint
{
    COLOR aColor;

    aColor.red = 0;
    aColor.green = 0;
    aColor.blue = 0;
    aColor.alpha = 0;
    NSUInteger width = self.frame.size.width;
    NSUInteger height = self.frame.size.height;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    long int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * ((NSUInteger)atPoint.y-1)) + (NSUInteger)atPoint.x*4;
    if((height * width * 4)<=byteIndex)
        return aColor;
    @try {
        aColor.red = imageRawData[byteIndex];
        aColor.green = imageRawData[byteIndex+1];
        aColor.blue = imageRawData[byteIndex+2];
        aColor.alpha = imageRawData[byteIndex+3];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"%@",e);
    }
    @finally {

    }


    return aColor;
}

-(void)setPixelColorAtPoint:(CGPoint)atPoint color:(COLOR)acolor
{
    NSUInteger width = self.frame.size.width;
    NSUInteger height = self.frame.size.height;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    long int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * ((NSUInteger)atPoint.y-1)) + (NSUInteger)atPoint.x*4;
    if((height * width * 4)<=byteIndex)
        return;
    @try {
        imageRawData[byteIndex] = acolor.red;
        imageRawData[byteIndex+1] = acolor.green;
        imageRawData[byteIndex+2] = acolor.blue;
        imageRawData[byteIndex+3] = acolor.alpha;
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"%@",e);
    }
    @finally {

    }

}

-(void)initializeCanvas
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [imageView release];
    isImageDataFreed = YES; 
    isFilling = NO;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
        [self initializeCanvas];
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    if(!imageRawData)
        [self prepareImageData];
    if(shouldShowOriginalImage)
        imageView.image = originalImage;
    else
        imageView.image = coloredImage;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [originalImage release];
    [coloredImage release];
    [pixelDataArray release];
}


-(BOOL)isColorStandardForRed:(unsigned char)__red green:(unsigned char)__green blue:(unsigned char)__blue
{
    if(0 == __red && 0 == __green && 0 == __blue)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}

-(BOOL)checkForValidRegionAtPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint
{
    COLOR colorAtPoint = [self getPixelColorAtIndex:touchPoint];
    loopCounter++;
    unsigned char _red   = colorAtPoint.red;
    unsigned char _green = colorAtPoint.green;
    unsigned char _blue  = colorAtPoint.blue;
    unsigned char _alpha1 = colorAtPoint.alpha;

    if(touchPoint.x <= 0 || touchPoint.y <= 0 || touchPoint.x >= self.frame.size.width ||touchPoint.y >= self.frame.size.height)
        return NO;
    if(red == _red && green == _green && blue == _blue && alpha1 == _alpha1)
        return NO;
    if(_alpha1 <= 225)
        return NO;
    if(_red <= 50 && _green <= 50 && _blue <= 50 && _alpha1 == 255)
        return NO;
    if(!([self isColorStandardForRed:_red green:_green blue:_blue]))
        return NO;
    return YES;
}

-(void)setColorAtPoint:(CGPoint)atPoint
{
    //loopCounter++;
    COLOR aColor;
    aColor.red = red;
    aColor.green = green;
    aColor.blue = blue;
    aColor.alpha = alpha1;

    [self setPixelColorAtPoint:atPoint color:aColor];
}

-(void)prepareImageData
{
    if(!imageRawData)
    {
        CGImageRef imageRef = [coloredImage CGImage];
        NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
        NSUInteger width = self.frame.size.width;
        NSUInteger height = self.frame.size.height;//CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
        NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
        imageRawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageRawData, width, height,
                                                     bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }
}

-(void)cleanUpImageData
{
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger width = self.frame.size.width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageRawData,  
                                             self.frame.size.width,  
                                             self.frame.size.height,  
                                             8,  
                                             bytesPerRow,  
                                             colorSpace,  
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);  
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);  
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    self.coloredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];  
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
}

-(void)refreshImage
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self cleanUpImageData];
    imageView.image = coloredImage;
    [pool release];
}


typedef struct queue_ { struct queue_ *next; } queue_t;
typedef struct ffnode_ { queue_t node; int x, y; } ffnode_t;

/* returns the new head of the queue after adding node to the queue */
queue_t* enqueue(queue_t *queue, queue_t *node) {
    if (node) {
        if(!queue)
            return node;
        queue_t *temp = queue; 
        while(temp->next)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = node;

       // node->next = queue;
        return queue;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* returns the head of the queue and modifies queue to be the new head */
queue_t* dequeue(queue_t **queue) {
    if (queue) {
        queue_t *node = (*queue);
        if(node)
        {
            (*queue) = node->next;
            node->next = NULL;
            return node;   
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

ffnode_t* new_ffnode(int x, int y) {
    ffnode_t *node = (ffnode_t*)malloc(sizeof(ffnode_t));
    node->x = x; node->y = y;
    node->node.next = NULL;
    return node;
}

-(void)floodFillAtPoint:(CGPoint)atPoint shouldRefresh:(BOOL)refresh
{

    queue_t *head = NULL;
    ffnode_t *node = NULL;

    node = new_ffnode(atPoint.x, atPoint.y);
    head = enqueue(head, &node->node);
    long int counter = 0;
    [self setColorAtPoint:atPoint];

    while((node = (ffnode_t*)dequeue(&head))) 
    {
        counter++;
        CGPoint aPoint = CGPointMake(node->x, node->y);
        free(node);
        CGPoint bPoint = aPoint;
        bPoint.x+=1;
        if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        {
            ffnode_t *node1 = new_ffnode(bPoint.x, bPoint.y); 
            head = enqueue(head, &node1->node);
            [self setColorAtPoint:bPoint];
        }
        bPoint = aPoint;
        bPoint.x-=1;
        if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        {
            ffnode_t *node1 = new_ffnode(bPoint.x, bPoint.y); 
            head = enqueue(head, &node1->node);
            [self setColorAtPoint:bPoint];
        }       
        bPoint = aPoint;
        bPoint.y+=1;
        if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        {
            ffnode_t *node1 = new_ffnode(bPoint.x, bPoint.y); 
            head = enqueue(head, &node1->node);
            [self setColorAtPoint:bPoint];
        }
        bPoint = aPoint;
        bPoint.y-=1;
        if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:bPoint])
        {
            ffnode_t *node1 = new_ffnode(bPoint.x, bPoint.y); 
            head = enqueue(head, &node1->node);
            [self setColorAtPoint:bPoint];
        }
    }
    if(refresh)
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(shouldRefresh) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];    
}


-(void)shouldRefresh
{
    self.regionCount += 1;
    //To detect if all the region/thread are completed; if YES then notify the delegate
    if(regionCount==9)
    {
        [floadFillTimer invalidate];
        isFilling = NO;
        [delegate fillingStateChanged:isFilling];
    }
    [self cleanUpImageData];
    imageView.image = coloredImage;
}

-(void)floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:(StackPoint*)point
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self floodFillAtPoint:point.point shouldRefresh:YES];
    [pool release];
}

-(void)floodFillInBackGroundAtPointWithRefresh:(StackPoint*)point
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self floodFillAtPoint:point.point shouldRefresh:YES];
    [pool release];
}

-(void)initiateFloodFillAtPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint
{
    loopCounter = 0;
    isFilling = YES;
    [delegate fillingStateChanged:isFilling];
    hasColored = YES;
    regionCount = 0;

    floadFillTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(refreshImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:floadFillTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    StackPoint *stackPoint = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:touchPoint];

    CGPoint floodPoint = touchPoint;

    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.x++;
    }
    floodPoint.x--;
    StackPoint *stackPoint1 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];

    floodPoint = touchPoint;
    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.x--;
    }
    floodPoint.x++;
    StackPoint * stackPoint2 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];
    floodPoint = touchPoint;
    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.y++;
    }
    floodPoint.y--;
    StackPoint *stackPoint3 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];
    floodPoint = touchPoint;
    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.y++;
    }
    floodPoint.y--;
    StackPoint *stackPoint4 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];


    floodPoint = touchPoint;

    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.x++;
        floodPoint.y++;
    }
    floodPoint.x--;
    floodPoint.y--;
    StackPoint *stackPoint5 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];

    floodPoint = touchPoint;
    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.x--;
        floodPoint.y--;
    }
    floodPoint.x++;
    floodPoint.y++;
    StackPoint * stackPoint6 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];
    floodPoint = touchPoint;
    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.x++;
        floodPoint.y--;
    }
    floodPoint.x--;
    floodPoint.y++;
    StackPoint *stackPoint7 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];
    floodPoint = touchPoint;
    while ([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:floodPoint])
    {
        floodPoint.x--;
        floodPoint.y++;
    }
    floodPoint.x++;
    floodPoint.y--;
    StackPoint *stackPoint8 = [StackPoint pointWithPoint:floodPoint];


    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint];    
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint1];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint2];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint3];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint4];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint5];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint6];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint7];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(floodFillInBackGroundAtPoint:) withObject:stackPoint8];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint aPoint = [aTouch locationInView:imageView];
    [self setColorForColoring];
    //This will toggle from uncolored state to colored state, also resets the colored image
    if(shouldShowOriginalImage)
    {
        self.coloredImage = originalImage;
        shouldShowOriginalImage = !shouldShowOriginalImage;
        [self freeImageData];
        [self prepareImageData];
        [delegate coloringStarted];
    }
    if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:aPoint] && !isFilling)
    {
        [self setColorForColoring];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self initiateFloodFillAtPoint:aPoint];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"splat%d",(rand()%10)+1];
        [[SoundEngine sharedSoundEngine] playSoundWithFileName:fileName delegate:nil];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint aPoint = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    [self setColorForColoring];
    //This will toggle from uncolored state to colored state, also resets the colored image
    if(shouldShowOriginalImage)
    {
        self.coloredImage = originalImage;
        shouldShowOriginalImage = !shouldShowOriginalImage;
        [self freeImageData];
        [self prepareImageData];
        [delegate coloringStarted];
    }
    if([self checkForValidRegionAtPoint:aPoint] && !isFilling)
    {
        [self setColorForColoring];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self initiateFloodFillAtPoint:aPoint];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"splat%d",(rand()%10)+1];
        [[SoundEngine sharedSoundEngine] playSoundWithFileName:fileName delegate:nil];
//        [self cleanUpImageData];
//        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}

-(void)toggleImage
{
    shouldShowOriginalImage = !shouldShowOriginalImage;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)setColorForColoring
{
    const CGFloat *colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents([self getColorForIndex:selectedColor]);
    red   =  (unsigned char)(colorComponents[0]*255);
    green =  (unsigned char)(colorComponents[1]*255);
    blue  = (unsigned char)(colorComponents[2]*255);
    alpha1 = (unsigned char)(CGColorGetAlpha([self getColorForIndex:selectedColor])*255);
}


-(void)setColor:(int)colorIndex
{
    selectedColor = colorIndex;
    //const CGFloat *colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents([self getColorForIndex:selectedColor]);
//  red   =  (unsigned char)(colorComponents[0]*255);
//  green =  (unsigned char)(colorComponents[1]*255);
//  blue  = (unsigned char)(colorComponents[2]*255);
//  alpha1 = (unsigned char)(CGColorGetAlpha([self getColorForIndex:selectedColor])*255);
}

-(void)cleanBuffer
{
    if(imageRawData)
    {
        int width = self.frame.size.width;
        int height = self.frame.size.height;
        int byteIndex = 0;
        for (int ii = 0 ; ii < (width*height*4) ; ++ii)
        {
            imageRawData[byteIndex] = 0;
            imageRawData[byteIndex + 1] = 0;
            imageRawData[byteIndex + 2] = 0;
            imageRawData[byteIndex + 3] = 255;
        }           
    }
}

-(void)freeImageData
{
    self.pixelDataArray = nil;
    free(imageRawData);
    imageRawData = NULL;
}

-(CGColorRef)getColorForIndex:(int)index
{
    switch (index) 
    {
        case 1:
            return [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
        case 2:
            return [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.200f green:0.200f blue:0.200f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
        case 3:
            return [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        case 4:
            return [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.062f green:0.658f blue:0.062f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
        case 5:
            return [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        case 6:
            return [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];
        case 7:
            return [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
        case 8:
            return [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor];
        case 9:
            return [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7f green:0.7f blue:0.7f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
        case 10:
            return [[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor];
        default:
            break;
    }


    return [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
}

@end
```

Additional Info:

StackPoint.h

```
    @interface StackPoint : NSObject {
        CGPoint point;
    }

    @property (nonatomic , assign) CGPoint point;
    +(StackPoint*)pointWithPoint:(CGPoint)_point;
    @end
```

StackPoint.m

```
    @implementation StackPoint
    @synthesize point;

    +(StackPoint*)pointWithPoint:(CGPoint)_point
    {
        StackPoint *__point = [[StackPoint alloc] init];
        __point.point = _point;
        return [__point autorelease];
    }

    -(id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
            point = CGPointZero;
        }
        return self;
    }

    @end
```